# Ubuntu/Debian Linux Locked User

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, debian, multiple-users

As the title suggests, I have locked a user account... However to test it I tried logging into the locked account. What I saw, which I expect many of you expect is the 'incorrect password' prompt at the command line.

My question is this;

Is there a file that I can edit so that blocked users get a prompt stating that their account is locked, as opposed to the incorrect password prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `usermod --expiredate 1970-01-01 <username>` it should display the message "Your account has expired; please contact your system administrator"

Comment: I just tried that, and I only got the login incorrect prompt...

Comment: Try to remove `--lock`